# azure logic app skip condition not working

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app that makes use of an *execute stored procedure action*.

It returns an `array` to iterate the data and pass it on to a service bus connector.

I have a condition to skip the service bus connector action execution if the stored procedure returns `null`. However, instead of being skipped the service bus connector throws an **error** stating `null` cannot be iterated.

I checked the condition using dummy values, and have confirmed that it works, but when `null` is encountered it's throwing **error**.

Comment: Hi, Can you add code from your workflow? You can get that code from the `Code view` `</>`

Comment: For logicapp questions if you share the code view it helps to find the cause of the issue and also repro.

Comment: Hard to read. Added correct formatting, grammar and general cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that the stored procedure actually returns an empty array if there are no elements? It seems that in this case it does not return any value (i.e. null)

Keep in mind that you can use the safe dereference operator that allows you to reference null properties of an object without a runtime error. You can also use the coalesce function that returns the first non-null object in the arguments passed in. For example, if you use this expression to handle a null action outputs:

```
@coalesce(action('myAction').outputs?.body?.arrayProperty, json('[]'))
```